# Make Recycleview item when clicked more interactive

Tags: java, android, xml

i have a question in gmail when one of the email is clicked it shows this animation[image]

How can i add this to my recyclerview and make my app more interactive ??

Answer (score 1):

You must have a layout you use fo each row, in this file, you can add to the parent layout

```
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

For example:

Application_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/applicationLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/applicationIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/applicationName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Application name"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This will make the row have an animation when the user will touch it.